# Database - Historic Data

Tags: c#, sql, database

Just wondering if you may have opinion on following.

Imagine that I have a simple app that stores invoices for customers.

To simplify invoice table is:

```
ID int,
NUMBER varchar(20)
CustomerID INT
```

Customer data is:

```
ID int
Number varchar(20)
Name varchar(30)
TaxID varchar(20)
...
```

Now because I want to keep my invoices with original customer data (so the data that customer has on a time when it was printed) I want to avoid changing original customer data at some point as otherwise all past invoices will have customers details changed as well.

What's the best approach?

Comment: keep customer data also with invoice...

Comment: Andrzej this is something that I would like to avoid really. Mainly because if my Customer table changes I will have to change a schema for invoice table etc. etc...

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially the difference between referential data and non-referential data. To avoid the referential problem of always accessing the current customer information, you need to write the customer information, as it was at the time, to the invoice table. So your invoice table schema would look more like:

```
ID int
NUMBER varchar(20) <-- also why is a column called NUMBER a varchar?!
CustomerID INT
CustomerNumber varchar(20)
CustomerName varchar(30)
CustomerTaxID varchar(20)
...
```

That way the data will always appear as it *was*, not as it *is* currently. The downside is that you store more data since you don't take advantage of normalization.

Comment: Invoice "numbers" with alpha characters are not uncommon.

Comment: @DStanley ahh, news to me. Thinking too much as a programmer, not enough as a business person.

Comment: This causes a lot of unnecessary repetition of customer data if you have repeat customers. Creating a customer history table to hold the customer details whenever the customer is updated, and logging the original customer details prior to updating the customers will preserve customer info. Then you just need to match up the date/time of the order to the date/time of the customer to find what their details were then.

Comment: @StarPilot or increment a version # on the `Customer` table and use that # in the `Invoice` table.

Comment: @Haney there are many ways to the solution of not repeating the customer info unnecessarily while keeping the customer info needed.

Comment: @DStanley yes thats the balance. After deeper analyse I can build a number based on 2 columns ( Number INT and 2 varchars ( prefix and suffix).. And then build them on fly to be displayed,

Answer (score 1):

If you would rather not store the information with the invoice (I would not), another solution would be to keep track of changes to the `Customer` data with a table like so:

```
HistoricID INT,
CustomerID INT,
....
ValidFrom DateTime NOT NULL,
ValidTo DateTime (NOT NULL) //read below for reason of ()
```

You can do this two ways: Insert to this table when you insert to your `Customer` table then update the row to make the `ValidTo` field have a value plus insert a row every time you update the `Customer` table. Or you can insert a row every time you update your `Customer` table reflecting the previous information.

If you go with the latter, `ValidTo` should be `NOT NULL`, and you will need to add a `ModifiedDate` field to the `Customer` table. Either way, this can be easily accomplished with triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for all the ideas. Meanwhile I've came up with some other possible solution and I wonder what's your opinion on it.

Basically I will have 2 Consumer tables - one that holds static data like phone numer , email code etc etc and another with customer details. Once important data changes I will just add details to details table and this ID will be used in the invoice table so:

```
[Customer]
ID int
Code varchar(20) 
....
Phone

[CustomerDetails]
ID INT
CustomerID Int
Name ...
Address
And other important data that I need to track

[Invoice]
ID
Number
CustomerDetailsID INT
```

At first sight it seems to be working fine.

Regards
Seb